# Update all rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

```
public function postWorkerActivityPlus()
{
    $current = Carbon::now();
    $WorkerActivity = Model::where('at_work',1)->where('updated_at','<',$current)->get();

    $d = $a / $b * $c ;

    foreach ($WorkerActivity as $key => $wa) {
        $updateActivity = Model::find($wa->id);
        if ($wa->worker_activity <= $a) {
            $updateActivity->worker_activity += $d;
            $updateActivity->save();
            return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'You updated worker');

        }
    }
}
```

This result updates first $updateActivity, when the first worker_activity reaches $a, proceed to second one etc. My task update all at once

Comment: what's your actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the return position

```
public function postWorkerActivityPlus()
{
$current = Carbon::now();
$WorkerActivity = Model::where('at_work',1)->where('updated_at','<',$current)->get();

$d = $a / $b * $c ;

foreach ($WorkerActivity as $key => $wa) {
$updateActivity = Model::find($wa->id);
if ($wa->worker_activity <= $a) {
$updateActivity->worker_activity += $d;
$updateActivity->save();

}
return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'You updated worker');
}
```